# GEB geb.error.UnexpectedPageException: Unable to find page match

Tags: geb

I am running into an intermittent 'geb.error.UnexpectedPageException: Unable' to find page error when using a element locator as listed below, method using the element also listed below.

Clicking the save button changes the page to one of two pages. My understanding was that using 'to:' with a list of pages would check the at checker for both pages and set the browser page to the first one that returns true.

In cases where this exception is thrown, the test is getting to the proper page(s). Experiencing this issue with Geb 0.9.3 and with 0.10.0.

```
static content = {
    saveButton(wait: true, to: [BenefitsAndDependentsPage, MemberHomePage]) { $('button', text:   contains('Save')) }
}

Page clickSaveButton() {
    saveButton.click()
    return browser.page
}
```

I'm Wondering if I am misunderstanding the use or if anyone else is experiencing similar issues?